# Is establishing passwordless SSH between 2 remote nodes is a bad idea?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption

I have scenario where my shell script executing on server A with user “X” need to connect server B thru SSH same user “X” and perform some tasks, similarly I have couple more machines server C, Server D, etc to perform same task.

I plan to generate `ssh-keygen -t rsa` with no passphrase on Server A under user “X” `.ssh` home and then do a `ssh-copy-id` to copy the public key to server B, C, etc… which get stored in authorizedkeys in there corresponding `.ssh` paths.

After this setup, my shell script works fine and I am able to perform all tasks.

But now I heard that keeping a unencrypted private key with user “X” on Server A is potential security risk. I can’t encrypt it passphrase because I need to have a passwordless SSH connection between Server A to B, C ,D etc.

Is it really bad approach? How to secure this? Any another secure way to achieve this?

Comment: If you can use an OpenSSH certificate, you have a secure setup. Setup the public key on the server that you want to connect to, and use the private key as password replacement, and don't store that on the server. You can use PuTTyGen to create the keys, and WinSCP to do SSH tasks.

Comment: Consider SSH agent forwarding

Comment: To me the big issue is this: Where are these servers located? Are they all public? Or in a private network? The reason why passwordless SSH its a *possible* risk is if someone somehow gets the private key that controls this all, that would allow them to connect to all of the machines as easy as you are using them. That said, this risk is really small. Especially if all of these servers are on a private network. If this were a public setup a good way to handle might be to restrict SSH access based on IP address. Do that and the passwordless risk is not so great.

Comment: The machines are in our private network, and private key which is in plaintext (unencrypted) is only under Server A user'X' home directory. we feel if we use such unencrypted keys will give no lateral movement to application user User'X'. Using OpenSSH certificates (not yet consider), SSH agent forwarding is an option which we can try.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to automate this process so that Server A can automatically log into an perform tasks on the other servers, then this is fine.  Many environments use SSH keys for this, and it's reasonably secure.

You should be sure that the access to the private key file is limited: it should be owned by an unprivileged user, ideally one with access to few other resources, and secured with 600 permissions.

I would also prefer an Ed25519 key over an RSA key (that is, `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`) if your systems support that.  Ed25519 keys provide security equivalent to a 3072-bit RSA key and are recommended by Mozilla.  Unlike RSA keys, which can be used with the weak SHA-1 algorithm, Ed25519 keys always sign data securely.

If you're very concerned about the security of using SSH keys in this way, you can rotate the keys periodically, which may be easier to do with an OpenSSH certificate authority, since such a CA can sign keys for a limited validity period.

If your goal is to have a user able to log in and run commands on Server A that can run on the other servers, then you probably just want to forward your agent, which you can do with `ssh -A`.